# Pass an image to another page in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am really sorry if it is against the rules of stack overflow but I need a bit of help in codes. 
I have been trying to pass the image captured through the CustomRenderer that works on the native iOS platform. I want to pass the image data from one page to another as done in Android through intent.PutExtra. 
Is there any way to do it?

Right now I am saving the image to the gallery but I need to display the image before saving.

```
var videoConnection = stillImageOutput.ConnectionFromMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
        var sampleBuffer = await stillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageTaskAsync(videoConnection);
        var jpegImage = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData(sampleBuffer);

        var photo = new UIImage(jpegImage);

        using(NSData imageData = photo.AsPNG())
        {
            byte[] ImageByte = new byte[imageData.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, ImageByte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));

        }



        photo.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error?.LocalizedDescription))
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"\t\t\tError: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure. My application is based on this: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ContentPage  if I click on take photo it will switch the native functionalities of the iOS. I need it that way because I am also changing few camera aspects which is not possible in forms.

Comment: if Forms pages are just C# classes - you can pass data between them using the constructor, public methods/properties, etc

Comment: Form pages are just for rendering. Once the button is clicked everything is switched to the Native. I am not sure if this makes sense to you.